# How to send message in a Telegram channel using Telegraf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I want to create a Bot that automatically keeps posting in a Telegram channel.I am using Node.js.
I am using Telegraf.js wrapper for Telegram API. You may even suggest any other suitable wrapper for this task.

Answer (score 6):

If your Channel is public. You need set admin in you channel. 
Use: `ctx.telegram.sendMessage(Channels_Username, 'your message')`

Example:

```
ctx.telegram.sendMessage('@birodarlar', 'Hi everyone')
```

If your Channel is Private You need set admin in you channel.Use: `ctx.telegram.sendMessage(Channels_id, 'your message')`

Example:

```
ctx.telegram.sendMessage('-145542325454', 'Hi everyone')
```

you can wiev your channels id with this link
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage
for 5 minutes you need public it and know channel id with url parsing

Answer (score 5):

Telegraph documentation is very comprehensive and you can find it at https://telegraf.js.org. I'm sure it will answer most of your questions.

If you want your bot to keep posting messages in a channel, simply execute this line of code in a loop:

```
ctx.telegram.sendMessage(CHANNEL_ID, 'your message')
```

Don't forget to replace `CHANNEL_ID` and `'your message'` with your own values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method

`bot.telegram.sendMessage(CHANNEL_ID, 'your message');`

instead of the suggested

`ctx.telegram.sendMessage(CHANNEL_ID, 'your message');`

on the other answers

Comment: best answer here for me, because i don't know how to get the ctx if the bot isn't starting or listening to a command.